ATMEGA32U4 Fast PWM 10-bit
I am developing a program on an ATmega32u4 board to control a FET (PWM -> low pass filter)
controlled current source. I am using the fast PWM mode with 10-bit resolution for timer 1.
The system clock is 16MHz (confirmed by measurement).
According to the datasheet, I expect a PWM frequency at the PB6 output of 15.6kHz (Fclk_io/1024).
But I only get 7.8kHz.
Is there any idea from the community to get the desired PWM-frequence?
void InitTimer_1(void)  
{
    //init TC1  
    TCNT1 = 0;    
    //using Port PB6 for PWM
    DDRB |= (1 < DDB6);

    //WGM mode 7, prescaler = 1  
    TCCR1A = (1<<COM1B1)|(1<<WGM11)|(1<<WGM10);  
    TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS10);
    
    //Setup PWM Registers 
    OCR1B = 1023;

}

int main(void) 
{ 
    //Disable interrupts 
    cli();  
    //Prescaler change enable
    CLKPR = 0x80; 
    //Set prescaler to zero
    CLKPR = 0x00;
    InitTimer_1();
    //Enable interrupts
    sei();
}

That's the answer to Yunnosh's question:
To check the system clock I use a pin-toggle with a delay of 1 millisecond. At the respective pin I see the expected output frequency of 500Hz.

How do you measure the frequency? I ask because of the suspicious factor of 2 between expected and measured frequency.

What compiler and C runtime do you use? In avr-libc exit from main() causes jump to reset vector.

What is fuse low byte value? What is F_CPU value when you measure frequency with delay? Also you configured OC1B as output but setup OCR1A register. Can you show oscillogram from OC1B pin?

The code you see above is just one part of a larger project. It documents the setup of the system clock and timer 1.
My problem is, as I said, that I only get half of the expected PWM output frequency. In a second step
I set up the PWM generation as a separate project. The result is now a correct output frequency of 15.6KHz.
This means that the Timer 1 function interacts with other parts of my project.

I will add the working code below.

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

void _delay_ms(double _ms);
bool up = true;
uint16_t pwm = 0;

void InitTimer_1(void)
{
    // for ATMega32u4
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB6);// Port PB6 as PWM-output
    TCNT1 = 0;
    //10-bit, WGM-mode 7
    TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A1)|(1<<WGM11)|(1<<WGM10);
    TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS10);
}


int main(void)
{
    //Disable interrupts
    cli();
    //Prescaler change enable
    CLKPR = 0x80;
    //Set prescaler to zero
    CLKPR = 0x00;
    InitTimer_1();
    //Enable interrupts
    sei();


    while (1) 
    {
        _delay_ms(200);
        OCR1B = pwm;
        if(up == true)
        pwm += 3;
        else
        pwm -= 3;

        if (pwm == 0x3ff)
        up = false;
        else if (pwm == 0x00)
        up = true;
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
